# What is this green box with a white arrow next to the word doc icon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, file

I was moving folders to a different location in sharepoint, where all the files within the folder moved except for this one.

What is distinct about this file from the others is the green box with a white arrow ned to the word doc icon. Refer to pic.
[image: Icon]
This file also seems to be corrupt as i get a Microsoft error "Word ran intoa problem opening this document in a browser. To view this document please open it in the desktop version.."
When I do, It is a blank document.

Does the arrow next to the icon indicate the file is corrupt or?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The icon indicates that the file is checked out to a user. If you hover over the icon, the tooltip will show you who has the file checked out. You can see who has checked out multiple files by adding the "Checked Out To" column to your library view.

Comment: In addition: this is called an "icon overlay". There are several icon overlays in SharePoint that are used for different purposes. A padlock, for e.g. signifies a record, i.e. a document that can no longer be changed.
Only the person who has the document checked out can check it back in, except for a site collection administrator. The admin can revert the check-out, but any changes that were made to the document while it was checked out will be lost.